# Why won't Android allow to run TabActivity?

Tags: android, tabs

The following code runs fine.

```
 public class MyActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



}
}
```

But the system crash when I do a

```
    public class MyActivity extends TabActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



}
}
```

I don't need anything from Main.xml. It's mindboggling why it won't run on second case.

Answer (score 0):

`TabActivity` requires a layout xml file, a little bit different that the ordinary.
 In that xml file you have to specify a `TabHost` and a `TabWigdet`.
You in both cases specify the same layout xml file, that's why your TabActivity never ran.

For more info [see here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html)

Comment: No, you don't have to use XML for tabActivity.  Take a look at IntentTabDemo.   TabHost host=getTabHost();
  
  host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("one")
      .setIndicator("CW")
      .setContent(new Intent(this, CWBrowser.class)));
  host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("two")
      .setIndicator("Android")
      .setContent(new Intent(this, AndroidBrowser.class)));
 }

Comment: If you use that way, remove then the `setContentView(R.layout.main)` from the `onCreate()`.

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.main) is not there but No help, still crashed

Comment: Can you post the AndroidManifest.xml file as well

Comment: It's zip file that enclosed everything, AndroidManidfest is inside.